# Is ‘upside down’ a depictive adjunct for ‘a note’?

Tags: adverbs, adjuncts

> “...and from yet another pocket inside his overcoat he pulled an owl
>   -- a real, live, rather ruffled-looking owl - a long quill, and a roll of parchment. With his tongue between his teeth he scribbled a note
>   that Harry could read **upside down**.” (Harry Potter and the
>   Sorcerer's Stone)

Is ‘upside down’ a depictive adjunct for ‘a note’?

Comment: It means that he can read the note upside down and the normal way.

Comment: You’re going to have to define your *“depictive adjunct”* thingie there.

Comment: A related question: [Waterway flowed sombre](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46364/waterway-flowed-sombre-should-j-conrad-have-used-an-adverb-not-an-adjective)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, *upside down* does not modify *a note*.  It modifies *read*.

Looking at the passage in context (typed up from my UK edition, which has some small differences):

> ‘Gallopin' Gorgons, that reminds me,’ said Hagrid, clapping a hand to his forehead with enough force to knock over a cart horse, and from yet another pocket inside his overcoat he pulled an owl - a real, live, rather ruffled-looking owl - a long quill and a roll of parchment. **With his tongue between his teeth he scribbled a note which Harry could read upside-down:**
>
> *Dear Mr Dumbledore,*
> 　*Given Harry his letter.  Taking him to buy his things tomorrow.
>
> Weather's horrible.  Hope you're well.*
> *Hagrid*

From context, we can see Hagrid doesn't intend for Harry to read the note at all; the intended recipient is Dumbledore.  From this, the most natural reading is that Harry is looking at it upside-down.

The other reading is grammatically possible but pragmatically questionable.

Comment: Thank you for your jotting down the British version. I'm thinking about getting it for better understanding.

Comment: Aha! The "translators" to "American" messed up. The clause is supposed to be a non-restrictive clause, so strictly speaking there should have been a comma before the "which" (in this case you probably wouldn't pause when speaking, so I think Rowling's leaving out the comma is entirely understandable, especially since she generally writes in a fairly informal style). But the people preparing the American edition took it as a restrictive clause, and changed "which" to "that".  It reads much better as a non-restrictive clause.

Comment: @PeterShor But *which* may be used with either restrictive or non-restrictive clauses (the only restriction is on *that*, which cannot be used with a non-restrictive clause); so the clause in question may be either. In any case, I don't think it affects the question at hand.

Comment: @StoneyB: Yes, but the American editors changed it to "that", which can ***only*** be used for restrictive clauses. This is why the sentence with "that" sounds odd. If you view it as a restrictive clause, the most natural inference is that Hagrid intended Harry to read it upside down.

Answer (score 9):

This is a tricky case.

Technically I suppose *upside down* modifies *that*, whose referent is *a note*; it certainly doesn't modify *Harry*, who I presume is normally oriented. The sentence certainly looks a lot like that in your earlier question, *She drank the coffee hot*.

Even more technically, however, *upside down* doesn't characterize the note, which is *right side up* with respect to Hagrid, but the relative orientations of the note *and* Harry. And it is of relevance neither to *Harry* nor to the *note* but to the verb *read*.

In this case I'm gonna revert to traditional grammar and vote for *adverb phrase* modifying the clause *that Harry could read*.

Comment: Isn't it an adverb phrase that modifies *just* the verb "read" and not the whole clause?

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone  That's one way of graphing it, and it's how it would have been done when I was  kid; but it seems to me to overlook the phrase's semantic connection to *Harry* and *that*. Like I said, it's tricky.

Comment: I think it would be perverse to parse it as *he scribbled **a note that Harry could read** upside down*. Your last sentence is credible, but it seems to me there's no need to associate *upside down* with anything other than *read*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I didn't think I'd suggested your perverse parsing; certainly *upside down* belongs to the second clause, not the first. But I don't see how it "modifies" *read*, at least not in the same sense that, say, *quickly* or *carefully* would.

Comment: @StoneyB: It seems to me it functions *exactly* the same as, for example, "quickly". Which is to say *upside down* modifies *read*. It just so happens that semantically it might well come to the same thing if we assume it modifies *scribbled*. But actually I imagine that's not the sense intended here - I'm guessing the text is something that reads identically right-side-up *and* upside-down, like, say, the date 1961 (in certain typefaces! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, I catch your drift now. My reading is: *Hagrid scribbled a note. Harry could read it, **even though it was, from his perspective, upside-down.***

Comment: @StoneyB: I didn't know Hagrid was the writer. Maybe he's too dumb to figure out a vertically-rotatable text. Whatever - I reckon it's the way Harry has to ***read*** it, regardless of whether he, the message, [or both?!], are "upside-down".