# "waterway ... flowed sombre" - Should Joseph Conrad have used an adverb, not an adjective?

Tags: word-choice, difference, adverbs, adjectives

**SPOILER ALERT:** This question asks about the last line of *Heart of Darkness* by Joseph Conrad. If you are reading the novel, you may want to skip this question.

> The offing was barred by a black bank of clouds, and the tranquil waterway leading to the uttermost ends of the earth flowed **sombre** under an overcast sky – seemed to lead into the heart of an immense darkness.

Should an adverb (i.e. sombrely) have been used to describe 'flowed'?
Are there any formal terms describing this issue? I question my doubt given Conrad's renown.

Obiter dictum: I lighted upon this  while reading [The Guardian's 'The 10 best… closing lines of books'](http://www.theguardian.com/culture/2012/jul/29/10-best-last-novel-lines).

Comment: It's called a 'bare adverb' or something like that. The 'ly' sometimes seems affected and in such cases aesthetics govern.

Comment: A related question: [is upside-down a depictive adjunct?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4566/is-upside-down-a-depictive-adjunct-for-a-note)

Comment: Another related question: [When adjectives become predicatives, do they also become adverbs?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26780/when-adjectives-become-predicatives-do-they-also-become-adverbs)

Comment: Another, at Linguistics SE: [Do predicative adjuncts modify nouns or verbs?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/do-predicative-adjuncts-modify-nouns-or-verbs)

Comment: "The waterway flowed(,) looking dark under an overcast sky."

Comment: What about Dylan Thomas' "Do not go gentle into that good night"?

Comment: You mean "flat" adverb (cf. http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/index.php?id=0030-flatadverbs&pid=mw_video ); but I find @Copper's answer more convincing (not an adverb at all).

Comment: @DamkerngT. "The waterway flowed, sombre, under an overcast sky"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've just been reading on "[depictive constructions](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Depictive_construction)" and it seems to be the term used by some lingusts to describe such constructions.

> The waterway flowed **sombre**.

The construction depicts the state of the waterway, not the manner of its flowing. [Compare](https://books.google.ru/books?id=CktoAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA343&ots=mg8f6V8d0I&dq=Depictive%20construction&hl=ru&pg=PA344#v=onepage&q=Depictive%20construction&f=false):

> 1. John shouted at them **angrily**. (describes the manner of his shouting)
> 2. John **angrily** read the review. (an intermediate case: describes John's state of mind too)
> 3. John left the party **angry**. (Depictive construction: John might have left the party in a civilized way, perhaps even smiling, but he was **angry** inside)

This thing called "adjective secondary predicate" seems to subdivide into depictive and [resultative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultative):

> Mary ate **tired**. (depictive over the subject: Mary was **tired**)
>   John ate the meat **raw** (depictive over the object: the meat was **raw**)
>   Johh pounded the metal **flat**. (resultative)
>   We drank the teapon **empty**. (resultative: the teapot has been emptied)
>   John fried the fish **dry**. ([resultative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultative#Adjectival_resultatives) *or* depictive: either the fish was fried to a dry condition, or John was dry while frying the fish)

You might read up on this and decide if I'm right.

Linguists seem to be still in disagreement as to how to treat such constructions. Judging by a quick perusal of different PDFs, some analyse the whole thing as a "complex predicate", leading to the use of the terms "resultative/depictive", some use the terms "small clause"/"adjunct" for resultatives and depictives respectively. I haven't yet got the difference.

---

Reference

- [Secondary Predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_predicate) - Wikipedia
- [Predicative Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression) - Wikipedia
- ["Types of secondary predication"](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftwpl.library.utoronto.ca%2Findex.php%2Ftwpl%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F6181%2F3170&ei=58rbVNCIGIiXgwTTsIHwBg&usg=AFQjCNG_gwGWhqMd8KZpLW_RsFCzhiveMw&bvm=bv.85761416,d.eXY) by Monica-Alexandrina Irimia (2005)
- ["Against the complex predicate analysis of secondary predication"](http://media.leidenuniv.nl/legacy/console17-asada.pdf) by Yuko Asada

---

P.S. Note that Conrad was a non-native speaker of English, although a brilliant writer. But in your example the usage seems idiomatic to me.

---

P.P.S. Related questions:

- [Is it possible to use adjectives as adverbs?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6275/is-it-possible-to-use-adjectives-as-adverbs)
- [Is ‘upside down’ a depictive adjunct for ‘a note’?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4566/is-upside-down-a-depictive-adjunct-for-a-note)
- [When adjectives become predicatives, do they also become adverbs?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/26780/8712)
- [Do predicative adjuncts modify nouns or verbs?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8438/do-predicative-adjuncts-modify-nouns-or-verbs) - at Linguistics SE

Comment: Downvoted?? Heck, no. I'm a bit surprised (and disappointed) to see answers here saying that an established author like Conrad must have made a gaffe. You've at least done some research and tried to explain why the construct is valid, instead of grading Conrad presumptious like a 4th-grade grammar teacher, and have given links to further reading. This is one of the better answers I've seen on ELL for some time.

Comment: +1, especially for "Linguists seem to be still in disagreement as to how to treat such constructions".

Comment: Certainly no gaffe.  If this had not already been available as correct English (which it was) Conrad would have been justified in creating a new new usage.  The sentence is infinitely better with "sombre" than with the adjective.

Comment: A more extreme example is Maurice Sendak's line "The ice thing only dripped and stared, and Ida mad knew the goblins had been there". This is much more questionable as "correct" grammar than Conrad's perfectly reasonable line, but wow, what a sentence! It's sometimes reproduced "fixed" as "…Ida, mad, knew…" and the weakness of that shows just why Sendak was justified in it.

Comment: Right. Resembles [hypallage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage) ('transferred epithet'). Compare P.G. Wodehouse "I balanced a thoughtful lump of sugar on my teaspoon", "he uncovered the fragrant eggs and b and I pronged a moody forkful", "As I sat in the bathtub, soaping a meditative foot".

Answer (score 6):

I will say that no, Conrad should **not** have written *somberly*, for something is either sombre or it is not sombre. There is no such state as "somber-like, in the manner of sombreness, or having the qualities or appearance of sombreness". Sombreness is a state, not a manner, not a show.

Comment: I will say we should be real careful about saying that an author like Conrad goofed up, and I'm a bit surprised at your claim. How about this: _The water moved slowly, like a funeral procession_. That sounds somber-like to me.

Comment: I am saying just the opposite of what you think I'm saying, @J.R. Conrad wrote *sombre*, not *somberly*. I think Conrad made the right choice.

Comment: Are you saying that _somberly_ shouldn't exist as a word? Dictionaries say it exists.

Comment: No, I'm saying that an artist of the likes of Conrad, when using the natural world to reflect an emotion, would avoid any locution that conveyed the idea that the natural world had the *semblance* of sombreness, which is exactly what the adverb *somberly* (as distinct from the adjective *sombre*) would convey.

Comment: @TRomano - My apologies, I misread your answer. I missed the "not", and mistakenly thought you had said, "I will say that no, Conrad should have written _somberly_..." How embarrasing! Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Not a problem, @J.R. I did phrase it sort of inside-out.

Answer (score 5):

The underlying concept is: The waterway was sombre. "To flow sombrely" would describe the manner of flowing, but  there is no sombre way of flowing or a happy way of flowing. Water can flow slowly, sluggishly, fast, but not sombrely.

The problem of adjectives after verbs in adverb position is very tricky and it takes some time to get a feeling for this problem. The school rule "after a verb follows an adverb" is really only a school rule. There should be added in brackets: (But there are a lot of cases where an adjective follows because the intent is not to describe the manner.)

**Edit:**
I looked up the etymology of **sombre** at etymonline. The meaning is 'gloomy, shadowy' from French and ultimately from Latin *sub* (= under) and *umbra* (= shadow). So we could clarify the use of the adjective sombre after flowed in this way:

> The water flowed (along) as under shadow. An expression made plausible as there are things that dim the light: an overcast sky and a dark cloud at the horizon and that fits with the last words: leading into the heart of darkness.

Comment: I've just read Longfellow's poem Excelsior where he says: The light of the household fires gleamed warm and bright. Instinctively you feel that "warmly/brightly" would be wrong. "warm/bright" don't modify the verb.  The expression is a variant for "the lights were warm and bright".

Answer (score 3):

It is OK. Same as you can say:

> The earth appeared **red** under the twilight sky.

where *red* is an adjective.

Using the example and a definition of [somber](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/somber):

> 1) dark and gloomy or dull

you could write:

> the tranquil waterway...flowed **dark and gloomy** under an overcast sky

Comment: It is not exactly the same. I would put to appear and to seem into the box linking verbs + adjective such as to be, to become/get, to remain/stay/keep and to seem/appear (to be).

Comment: Nice concrete application of the theory @CopperKettle laid out.

Answer (score 2):

**Somber** is correct. It’s a complement. Whether to call it a subject complement, predicative adjective, or something else is a matter of debate. It’s also an unusually clever and poetic use of English grammar.

Here is a similar, more ordinary example of this construction:

> Rinse the shirt under cold running water until the water **runs clear**. [[Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=J_msEC26aqMC&lpg=PA57&dq=%22rinse%20the%20shirt%20under%20cold%20running%20water%20until%20the%20water%20runs%20clear%22&pg=PA58#v=onepage&q=%22rinse%20the%20shirt%20under%20cold%20running%20water%20until%20the%20water%20runs%20clear%22&f=false)]

### The word *somber*

The primary meaning of **somber** is: somewhat dark, as if under a shadow. This agrees with **overcast sky**. But a more common meaning of **somber** is a certain melancholy, solemn mood. The water doesn’t have a mood, of course, but I’m sure Conrad chose this word carefully, since the characters were surely in a somber mood after the death just discussed and the lie just told to the deceased’s fiancée. The mood isn’t part of the literal meaning of the sentence, but that meaning will affect a reader.

### The grammatical construction

It’s ambiguous whether the water *became* somber as it flowed—that is, led into darkness—or whether it was somber everywhere. [Copperkettle’s answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/46391/6700) provides linguistic terminology for these two kinds of complement, and mentions that scientists are still figuring out precise categories for them. However, **somber** in this sentence calls upon both grammatical meanings simultaneously. One meaning is echoed by **under an overcast sky** and the other meaning is echoed by **lead into the heart of an immense darkness**. To pick either “the state of the water” or “the shade that the water took on as it flowed” would miss the deliberate double use of the same complement, which gives the sentence its unique and memorable structure.

Comment: +1. Thank you for the literary analysis and explanation of the double entendre of **somber** in your last para.

Answer (score 0):

The word in question is part of a participle clause.

> , and the tranquil waterway leading to the uttermost ends of the earth flowed **(being)** sombre under an overcast sky –

I can convert it to a adverbial clause as below.

> , and the tranquil waterway leading to the uttermost ends of the earth flowed **(while it was)** sombre under an overcast sky –

Answer (score 0):

One waxes lyrical, not lyrically. Same construct.

Comment: To wax can be seen as a linking verb like to be, to become, to remain etc.