# In "I have grown very fond of Alec", why is an adjective ("fond") used instead of an adverb?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, linking-verbs

> I have grown very fond of Alec.

I think this sentence looks weird.

I suppose **grown** is a verb, and should be followed by an adverb.
But I don't think **fond** is an adverb.

Is this sentence correct in grammar? Thanks.

Comment: It is correct. "Over the years we've grown very fond of each other." from Longman dictionary. Fond is an adjective. Grown = be. I have grown=been very fond of Alec. Grown here connotes gradual process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is grammatically correct. [From Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fond), "Over the years we’ve grown very fond of each other". In this sentence structure, the word "Fond" is an adjective. Grown acts like *be*. I have grown (been) fond of Alec. Gradual connotes a gradual process of fondness.

You can use the word *grow* plus an adjective, which means become.  I have grown (increasingly) annoyed/satisfied.   The sound was growing louder.

Answer (score 6):

"to grow" is a copula verb or linking verb, which are connected with predicative adjectives.Google for a list of copula verbs, eg

[Copula verbs](http://www.usingenglish.com/glossary/copula-verb.html)

The copula verbs are mainly to be, to become + variants and to stay + variants. A second group can be labelled verbs of perception (to look, to sound, to smell, to taste, to feel).

The rule that verbs are followed by adverbs is a beginners' rule and concerns only adverbs of manner. But the rule does not mention all the cases where you need an adjective after a verb.

Answer (score 4):

MUCH more simply, 'very fond' is describing the the person (the noun: in this case "I"), not the action of becoming fond (the verb: "growing fond of")
Therefore it is an adjective.

Compare: "I have quickly grown tired of confusing grammar rules" where quickly is an adverb because it relates to the action.
(i.e. the process of growing tired was quick, not "I" am quick)

Comment: Good explanation. "I stayed hungry for days" (describes me)  vs. "I stayed hungrily for days" (in the same hotel or whatever); describes the way of staying there. (That example is a bit deceiving because the second "stay"  -- "take residence" -- is no copula). But there are even more obscure examples when the verb is not a classic copula, like "[the river] flowed sombre under an overcast sky" (Joseph Conrad), cf. http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/46364/15471. It's easy to construct more examples -- "I drove home silent" (the *driving* may still have made a lot of noise) etc.

Comment: +1 for a good non-technical answer and the contrasting example.

Answer (score 2):

Some verbs take Direct Objects:

- Bob ate a carrot.

In the sentence above, *a carrot* is the Direct Object. Now a Direct Object is a special type of Complement. A Complement is a phrase that fills a special slot (space) set up by the verb. There are other types of Complement that verbs can take. For example the verb *GO* takes Locative Complements. These tell us about *where* something is or *where* something is going:

- Bob went [into the cave].

Locative Complements are usually preposition phrases.

Another type of Complement is a Predicative Complement. A Predicative Complement gives us more information about the Subject or Object of the sentence.:

- Bob was happy
- The elephant became angry.
- The flowers made the orangutan happy.

In the first sentence the Predicative Complement is *happy*. It describes the Subject of the sentence, Bob. In the second example the verb *became* is taking a Predicative Complement, *angry*. Again this describes the Subject of the sentence, the elephants. The last sentence is different. Here the verb *made* is taking two Complements. One is the Direct Object, *the orangutan*, the second Complement is the Predicative Complement *happy*. This time the Predicative Complement is describing the Direct Object, *the orangutan*, not the Subject, *the flowers*.

Predicative Complements are often adjective phrases, but they can also be noun phrases or preposition phrases:

- Bob was [a builder].
- Bob was [in a hurry].

Notice that in the first sentence there is only one person. The phrase *a builder* just describes the Subject, *Bob*.

However, Predicative Complements are almost *never* adverbs:

- Bob was happily. (ungrammatical)

**The Original Poster's sentence**

> I have grown very fond of Alec.

When the verb *GROW* is used with this meaning, it means something similar to *BECOME*. Like the verb *BECOME*, the verb *GROW* also takes Predicative Complements. These are nearly always adjective phrases (but they can be preposition phrases too).

- Bob became irritable.
- Bob grew irritable.

In these sentences the adjective *irritable* is describing the Subject, Bob. Notice that we don't usually use adverbs to describe nouns. If we try to use an adverb as a Predicative Complement here, it will be ungrammatical:

- *Bob became irritably.
- *Bob grew irritably.

In the Original Poster's example, the adjective phrase is *very fond of Alec*. It describes the Subject, *I*. We cannot use an adverb here, because this phrase is the Predicative Complement of the verb *grew*.

Comment: Any helpful advice from the downvoter?

Comment: Unfortunately someone has gone on a bit of a spree across the site. Always helpful to add a comment to explain a downvote, people.