# Can “exist” be followed by an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, secondary-predicates

On Wikipedia, I read a sentence like this:

> *Logical realism posits that logical truth **exists independent** of human ideas.*

Is that grammatical? According to Wikipedia, this seems connected to [adjuncts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)) and [predicative expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression). If it is grammatical, what criteria can be used to tell what verbs can be used in this way?

Comment: *Independent of human ideas* is a ***secondary predicate***. We have a couple of dozen questions about this sort of clausal constituent, tagged [tag:secondary-predicates], and a brief definition at the [tag wiki](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/secondary-predicates/info). At least in theory just about *any* verb could take a secondary predicate.

Comment: It's not clausaI, it's phrasal. I see no reason to call it a predicative adjunct referring to the subject "logical truth". I'd replace "independent" with the adverb "independently" and analyse "Independently of human ideas" as an AdvP modifying "exists".

Comment: [*Do I exist alone in my mind or is there something else going on?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22do+i+exist+alone%22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, although this construction is available to almost *any* verb.  StoneyB calls it a "secondary predicate" while BillJ calls it (I believe) an "adverbial predicate", but either way it's a phrase that *acts* like an adverb to modify the verb.  Another example [from a related question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46364/waterway-flowed-sombre-should-joseph-conrad-have-used-an-adverb-not-an/46391#46391):

> ... the tranquil waterway leading to the uttermost ends of the earth flowed **sombre under an overcast sky**.

Personally, this structure feels somewhat *literary*.  In everyday exposition the author would be more likely to use the adverb *independently*.

Comment: Hmm.  Replace "exists" with "is" and "independent of human ideas" looks like an ordinary subject complement.  Is there any particular reason to avoid considering this as a copular use of a typically intransitive verb?  The inverse happens in the classical "I think; therefore, I am".

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan  I'm not really interested in the *classification* of grammar structures, but there seems to be a slight difference between this example and your example.  In your example the secondary phrase helps describe *what* is "logical truth" while in this example it modifies *how* logical truth *exists*.   Granted this *makes* little difference to the underlying meaning, but it should affect how linguists describe the grammar, I think.