# What is a positive adjective that describes a person who follows a routine?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I’m writing a character’s description, and I’m stuck on my hero’s “greatest strength”. He is very routine, and organized (which manifests more as he’s responsible and less as stubborn inflexibility). The word also need to have a positive connotation of course, and need to imply he goes through with promised commitments- his yes means yes and his no means no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["waterway ... flowed sombre" - Should Joseph Conrad have used an adverb, not an adjective?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46364/waterway-flowed-sombre-should-joseph-conrad-have-used-an-adverb-not-an)

Comment: It may not exactly what you are looking for, but "fuddy-duddy" might work. It depends on the depths of your character, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You have described a **phlegmatic** personality. The word "phlegmatic" is seldom used, but if you look up the word for its synonyms, you'll find several words that might be what you seek, such as "cool, calm, composed."

Answer (score 0):

In a *positive* sense, somebody who always does the same thing (especially in the case of honouring their commitments) is somebody who is [**reliable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reliable):

> **1** : suitable or fit to be relied on : DEPENDABLE
>   **2** : giving the same result on successive trials

In other words, you could say the following about him:

> He's *reliable*. I can trust that he will be organized, be there on time, and do what he says.

---

Of course, some people also use the word *reliable* when talking about somebody's negative qualities (*you can rely on him to make a mistake*), but it's said in a sarcastic sense, one that twists the normal meaning. It has the same contradiction as *you can trust him to lie*.